# How to make an io images file directory universal so the program can be packaged into a .jar or .exe file?

Tags: image, file, jar, directory, exe

I am having trouble packaging my program into an .exe or .jar because the file directory for images isn't universal.

for example our current directory looks like this:

bufferedImageExample = ImagIO.read("K:/projectFolder/image.gif")

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `java.lang.Class.getResource()` to load images right from .jar and `java.util.Properties` to tell your app where various directories are.

Comment: Thank you this looks like what I need. Can you give me an example of how to implement those two because I cant seem to figure it out from java's website.

Comment: (Simplified:) for a class `Foo`, `Foo.getResourceAsStream('foo.gif')` will give you an input stream to access a file `foo.gif` situated at the same place as `Foo.class`. Figure `Properties` yourself — it's just a hash table with `load()` and `store()` for easy loading from / storing to a config file.